# Passing a script from runspacepool

Tags: multithreading, powershell, exchangewebservices, runspace

I am trying to work on an existing script that I had some assistance from in another thread. With some member assistance I was able to get my script to run using the "ThreadJob" module, however I was hoping I can also make use of runspacepools in conjunction with the ThreadJob to make it run faster.

In my code I post below, I am printing out a line to notify me that the function get's called. And I can see it is getting called. So it makes me think that line 56 and line 59 are incorrectly being called and I can't figure out how to call them.

if I run the "$rootPath\UpdateContacts\UpdateContacts.ps1" file manually through powershell ISE, it runs fine (obviously outside of the runspace), but I'd like to try and get it to work within the runspacepool.

Here is what I'm working with. I think I am pretty close.

```
begin
{
    CLS

    [switch]$MultiThread=$true

    $rootPath = $(Split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.path -Parent)

    $userEmail = "user@domain.com"
    
    $SessionState = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()
    $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 10,$Sessionstate, $Host)
    $RunspacePool.Open()
    $Jobs = @()
    
}

process 
{
    function ContactUpdater()
    {
        ##################### Start Comparing Data #####################

        #Our Array of values we will be comparing
        [array]$CompareValues = "FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","DisplayName","Email","Mobile","TelephoneNumber","Title","Dept","Company"

        for($i=0; $i -lt $CompareValues.Count; $i++)
        {
            #First let's create 2 variables that will hold the info we want
            $A = ($Users).($CompareValues[$i])
            $B = ($Contacts).($CompareValues[$i])

            ##################### Update Contacts #####################

            #Only Run if there are contacts; otherwise there is nothing for us to compare
            if(($NULL -ne $B))
            {
                #Displays all differences
                #$Differences = [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$a, [object[]]$b) + [Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$b, [object[]]$a))

                #Displays what accounts we need to import
                $NeedsToBeAdded = [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$a, [object[]]$b))

                #Displays what accounts we need to delete because they no longer exist
                $NeedsToBeDeleted = [string[]]([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]]$b, [object[]]$a))
            }
        }
            ##################### Import All Contacts #####################

        if($NULL -eq $Contacts)
        {
            Write-Host "I am in the import"
            
            # Load UpdateContacts function in memory
            . "$rootPath\UpdateContacts\UpdateContacts\UpdateContacts.ps1"

            #Write-host "Importing Contacts. This could take several minutes."
            & "$rootPath\UpdateContacts\UpdateContacts.ps1"
        }
    }

    if($MultiThread)
    {
        foreach($userEmail in $EmailAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                ##################### Create Contact Folder #####################

                if($NULL -eq $folderId)
                {
                    $start = [datetime]::UtcNow

                    Write-Host "Creating Contacts Folder"

                    Try
                    {
                        while($NULL = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UPN/contactFolders/$folderId" -Headers $headers -Method get))
                        {
                            $NewContactFolder = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UPN/contactFolders" -Body $ContactsFolderBody -Headers $headers -Method post -ContentType 'application/json'
                            sleep -Milliseconds 1
                            $folderId = $($NewContactFolder.id)
                        }
                    }
                    Catch
                    {
                        Out-Null
                    }

                    Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`t`tCreated Contacts Folder in: $('{0:N2}' -f ([datetime]::UtcNow - $start).TotalSeconds) seconds"
                    Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" ""
                }

                ##################### Getting All User Info #####################

                $start = [datetime]::UtcNow

                $Users = & $rootPath\GetUserInfo\GetUserInfo.ps1

                Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`t`tFinished Getting all User Info in: $('{0:N2}' -f ([datetime]::UtcNow - $start).TotalSeconds) seconds"
                Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" ""

                ##################### Getting Contact Info #####################

                if($NULL -ne $folderId)
                {
                    $start = [datetime]::UtcNow

                    $Contacts = & $rootPath\GetContactInfo\GetContactInfo.ps1

                    Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`t`tFinished Getting all Contact Info in: $('{0:N2}' -f ([datetime]::UtcNow - $start).TotalSeconds) seconds"
                    Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" ""
                }

                ##################### Import Contacts #####################

                $start = [datetime]::UtcNow

                CLS

                if($NULL -eq $ImportMsg)
                {
                    Write-host "Importing Contacts. This could take several minutes."
                    $ImportMsg = "Ran"
                }

                $ContactImporter = ContactUpdater

                Add-Content "$rootPath\progress.txt" "`t`tFinished Importing Contact Info in: $('{0:N2}' -f ([datetime]::UtcNow - $start).TotalSeconds) seconds"

            }
            catch
            {
                $LogFile = "$rootPath\log.txt"
                $errcond = $_.Exception.Message
                $timestamp = (get-date).DateTime
                "Time of exception: $timestamp" | Out-File $LogFile -Append
                "User: $userEmail" | out-file $LogFile -Append
                $errcond | out-file -FilePath $LogFile -append
            }
            
            1..10 | Foreach-Object {
                $PowershellThread = [powershell]::Create()
                $PowershellThread.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
                $PowershellThread.AddScript($ContactImporter).AddArgument($userEmail)
                $Jobs += $PowershellThread.BeginInvoke()
            }
        }
    }
}

end
{
    if($MultiThread)
    {
        while ($Jobs.IsCompleted -contains $false) 
        {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        }

        $RunspacePool.Close() | Out-Null
        $RunspacePool.Dispose() | Out-Null
    }
}
```

The part in the "Import all Contacts" section within the ContactUpdater() Function, should call the script:

```
& "$rootPath\UpdateContacts\UpdateContacts.ps1"
```

That script looks like this:

```
# Save the function in a scriptBlock, we need this
# so we can pass this function in the scope of the ThreadJobs
$updateContacts = "function UpdateContacts { $function:updateContacts }"

# Define the Number of Threads we are going to use
# (Get-CimInstance win32_processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
# Can give you a good perspective as to how many Threads is safe to use.
$numberOfThreads = 10

# $users is the array we want to process with
# the UpdateContacts function. 
# Grouping the users in chunks so each running Job can process
# a chunk of users. Each chunk will contain around 50 users to process.
$groupSize = [math]::Ceiling($users.Count / $numberOfThreads)
$counter = [pscustomobject]@{ Value = 0 }
$chunks = $users | Group-Object -Property {
    [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $groupSize)
}

foreach($chunk in $chunks)
{
    # Capture this chunk of users in a variable
    $thisGroup = $chunk.Group
    
    # This is what we are running inside the scope
    # of our threadJob
    $scriptBlock = {

        # Pass our variables to this scope
        $UPN = $using:UPN
        $folderID = $using:folderId
        $headers = $using:headers
        $contactsBody = $using:contactsBody
        $ImportMsg = $using:ImportMsg

        # First we need to define the function inside this scope
        . ([scriptBlock]::Create($using:updateContacts))

        # Loop through each user
        foreach($user in $using:thisGroup)
        {
            UpdateContacts -User $user
        }
    }

    # ThrottleLimit is the number of Jobs that can run at the same time.
    # Be aware, a higher number of Jobs running does NOT mean that the
    # task will perform faster. This always depends on your CPU & Memory.
    # And, this case in particular, the number of requests your URI is able to handle
    Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ThrottleLimit $numberOfThreads
}

# Now we should have 10 Jobs running at the same time, each Job
# is processing a chunk of 50 users aprox. (500 users / 10)
# the output of all Jobs:
$result = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait

# Free up memory:
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```

That code above, starts a threadjob and launches another function in "$rootPath\UpdateContacts\UpdateContacts\UpdateContacts.ps1"

And that script looks like this:

```
Function UpdateContacts($User)
{
        #FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, DisplayName, SamAccountName, Email, Mobile, TelephoneNumber, Title, Dept, Company, Photo, ExtensionAttribute2
        $ContactsBody = @"
        { 
            "givenName"      : "$($User.FirstName)",
            "middleName"     : "$($User.MiddleName)",
            "surname"        : "$($User.LastName)",
            "fileAs"         : "$($User.LastName)",
            "displayName"    : "$($User.DisplayName)",
            "jobTitle"       : "$($User.Title)",
            "companyName"    : "$($User.Company)",
            "department"     : "$($User.Dept)",
            "mobilePhone"    : "$($User.Mobile)",
            "homePhones"     : ["$($User.TelephoneNumber)"],
            "emailAddresses": 
            [
                {
                    "address": "$($User.Email)",
                    "name": "$($User.DisplayName)"
                }
            ]
        }
"@
        Try
        {
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UPN/contactFolders/$folderId/contacts" -Headers $headers -Body $ContactsBody -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' | Out-Null

            #After each user clear the info
            $User = $NULL
        }
        Catch
        {
            if($error)
            {
                $User
                $error
                pause
            }

            $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            $_.Exception.ItemName
        }
}
```

Comment: At this point it's probably easier to pare your question down to just what you're trying to multithread. Is it comparing each user's `$Contacts` to a master list `$Users`? Is it updating the contacts through the api? What happens with `$NeedsToBeAdded`? Lines 56 and 59 are blank, so I think you're missing some info

Comment: Sorry about that. What I am doing is trying to add the function to a variable like this: $ContactImporter = ContactUpdater. Then I call it in the runspace like this: $PowershellThread.AddScript($ContactImporter).AddArgument($userEmail). When it goes into the ContactUpdater() Function, I'm not too worried about the "Update Contacts" section. I'm trying to launch a powershell script from the "Import All Contacts" section. It's not starting up for some reason. If it helps, I can post that script in the original question. All I know is when I launch that script through ISE, it runs fine.

Comment: Updated the original topic and posted all the code so it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: There's still too much going on for me to really tell. Can you try checking the output of your runspaces? For you it's something like `$PowershellThread.Streams.Error`